# Can we solve $A \cos (\theta + \alpha) = \sin 2 \theta$ where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ and $A, \alpha$ are constants?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, transcendental-equations

What are solutions to $$A \cos (\theta + \alpha) = \sin 2 \theta$$ where $\theta \in [0, 2\pi)$ and $A, \alpha$ are constants?

Graphically, this seems to have 2, 3, or 4 solutions, but I don't know how to find them analytically.

In fact, my goal isn't to find $\theta$, but rather characterize for which regions of $A, \alpha$ there are 4 solutions.  I believe this will be one means of solving how many normals of a given ellipse intersect a given point.

---

Can we simplify via trig identities?
$$q = A \cos \alpha \\
r = A \sin \alpha \\
q \cos \theta - r \sin \theta - 2 \sin \theta \cos \theta = 0$$

What about expanding the Taylor Series?

Comment: Substituting $$\sin\theta={2t\over 1+t^2},\quad \cos\theta={1-t^2\over 1+t^2},$$ where $t=\tan(\theta/2)$ gives a quartic equation in $t$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca Nice, because graphically I can get up to 4 solutions.  Could you please explain how you did that substitution? I can prove that it works.  But where did it come from?! Could you consider expanding your comment into a full anaswer?

Comment: This is the standard tangent-of-the-half-angle substitution, $t=\tan(\theta/2)$.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Answer (score 0):

Comment: We may write:

$A \cos \theta \cos \alpha-\sin\theta \cos\theta=A \sin \theta \sin \alpha + \sin \theta \cos \theta$

$$\tan \theta=\frac {A \cos \alpha-\sin \theta}{A \sin \alpha - \cos \theta}\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space(1)$$

Isolating $\theta$ leads to a mess of a trig. equation of degree 3. So we argue on relation (1):

1): $\theta=2k\pi\Longleftrightarrow A \cos \alpha=0$

Suppose $A\neq 0$, then $\cos \alpha=0\Rightarrow \alpha=(2k+1)\frac{\pi}2$; in $[0, 2\pi]; \alpha=\frac{\pi}2,.or. \frac{3\pi}2$

2): $\theta =\frac{\pi}4\Longleftrightarrow A \cos \alpha-\sin \theta=A \sin \alpha + \cos\theta\rightarrow A=\frac{\sqrt 2}{\cos \alpha-\sin \alpha}$

$\Rightarrow 0\leq\alpha <\frac {\pi}4$ or $\frac {\pi}4<\alpha\leq\frac{\pi}2$

(1) and (2) says there are real solutions for A and $\alpha$ in range $0<\theta<\frac {3\pi}2$

For $\theta=\frac{\pi}2$, relation (1) is undefined and there is no solutions for A and $\alpha$. That is equation has no solution like $(2k+1)\frac {\pi}2$ . These results are competent with the graphs shown below:

[image]

In this graph $A=\frac{\pi}4, B=\frac{\pi}2, C=\frac{3\pi}4, D=\pi\cdot\cdot\cdot$

Orange: $y=\sin 2\theta$

Blue: A=1, $\alpha=1$ which gives $y= \cos(\theta+1)$ $\theta\approx \frac {\pi}{16}$

Brown: A=2, $\alpha=1$ which gives $y+ \cos (\theta+1)$, $\theta\approx\frac{\pi}{10}$